# ionic 4 (android) get image (OBJECT FILE) from gallery (FILE_URI) and upload via API

Tags: android, angular, cordova, parse-platform, ionic4

I'm trying to implement a simple application using **Ionic v4 angular and cordova.** Just select a photo and upload it to a **parse server (back4app.com)**. But I couldn't do it.

This is my code:

home.page.ts

```
import { ParseService } from '../service/parse.service';

import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { WebView } from '@ionic-native/ionic-webview/ngx';
```

```
  selectPhoto() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      correctOrientation: true 
    }
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
      // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
      // let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      // console.log(imageData);

      this.fileToUpload = imageData;

      this.phototoshow = this.webview.convertFileSrc(imageData);

    }, (err) => {
      // Handle error
    });
  }
```

```
 onSubmit() {

    this.presentLoading();

    // return this.apiService.upload(this.phototoshow).subscribe((data: any) => {
    return this.apiService.upload(this.fileToUpload).subscribe((data: any) => {
          console.log(data);
    }
}
```

service.ts

```
upload(img1): Observable<any> {
    // console.log(data);
    return this.http.post(this.apiURL + '/files/img.jpg', img1,{
      headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': this.APP_ID,
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': this.REST_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type':'image/jpeg'
      }
    })
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }
```

I was able to upload the image with "input type = file" in the form ... **but selecting the image from the gallery with the cordova plugin camera ... it only returns FILE_URI but I need the OBJECT FILE to upload via api rest.**

I have read enough info on the web **but it is old information** that does not help me. I hope someone can help me with the problem. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem:

```
  startUpload() {
      this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(this.fileToUpload)
      // this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(imgEntry.filePath)
          .then(entry => {
              (entry as FileEntry).file(file => this.readFile(file))
          })
          .catch(err => {
              alert('Error while reading file.');
          });
  }

  readFile(file: any) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
          const imgBlob = new Blob([reader.result], {
              type: file.type
          });
          this.onSubmit(imgBlob);
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you this was a big help.